# Node MySQL query syntax error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm attempting to query my database, but am getting the error:

> ```
> Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual th
> at corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'gr
> oup = 'new_fire', date = '2014-03-16', price = '', customer = '', seller = 'no'
> at line 1
> ```

But I can't seem to find the syntax error. I assume it has to do with the way that I'm putting the query together with the `nodeMySQL` module.

Here's my relevant node query snippet:

`var salesData =  [category, group, date, price, customer, name, commission];`

...

```
connection.query(
'INSERT INTO `officeball`.`sales_entries` SET category = ?, group = ?, date = ?, price = ?, customer = ?, seller = ?, commission = ?',
salesData
)
```

And finally the query generated by phpmyadmin that I mean to execute:

```
INSERT INTO `officeball`.`sales_entries` (`sale_id`, `category`, `group`, `date`, `price`, `customer`, `seller`, `accepted`, `commission`, `commission_status`) VALUES ('', 'fire', 'new_fire', '2014-03-16', '123', 'joey bob', 'node user', '', '34', '')
```

I left the `accepted` and `commission_status` out in the node query, they can remain blank.

**Is my error in this query?**

Answer (score 4):

`group` is mysql reserved keyword, surround it by backticks like this:

```
   INSERT INTO `officeball`.`sales_entries` SET category = ?, `group` = ? .....
```

Here are the [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) from documentation.

Comment: Ahh. I would've never discovered that. You've saved my much time dear sir. Thanks!